# systemd user mode error on CentOS 7.0 (1406) server

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

I'm trying to run systemd user mode on CentOS 7.0 server (no X11 installed).
e.g.

```
systemctl --user start hw.service
```

it reacts:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

If I add

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

and run again, it reports:

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

Can anyone shed light on this? btw, systemctl --version reports:

```
systemd 208
+PAM +LIBWRAP +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**CentOS doesn't support "systemd --user".** Their packages outright remove that part of systemd. (Notice how there's no `user@.service`, among other things.)

---

That said, the libdbus' autolaunch error message is misleading, and your `$DISPLAY` is wrong.

The error message really says "[systemctl couldn't reach systemd at the private address, so it asked libdbus to use the session bus, but] there was no session bus address explicitly set, so libdbus tried to autolaunch one, but couldn't do that either".

Now, if you *were* trying to use D-Bus session autolaunch, then just setting $DISPLAY wouldn't be enough – it would expect an X11 server like Xorg to already be running at :1 or such (in which case, $DISPLAY would already be set).

But `systemctl --user` doesn't really want autolaunch – it expects to find systemd at a specific location, `/run/user/$UID/bus` and `/run/user/$UID/systemd/private` – so launching a new bus would be useless as it wouldn't have systemd there. So recent versions no longer use autolaunch (or libdbus for that matter).

Comment: Upvoted the answer though I really don't like it!